# React Native 0.29+ without dev mode in iOS?

Tags: react-native

After upgrading to RN 0.29.1 I dont have a URL in my AppDelegate.m file where I can say dev=false... is there an obvious way to turn off dev mode that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem as though facebook has updated the docs on how to use the new `RCTBundleURLProvider`. For now I have just added back in the old `URLWithString` from previous versions and it works just fine:

**Add:**

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ipaddress:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

**Comment:**

```
[[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] setDefaults];
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
```

Comment: how crazy is this right? seems like a pretty basic thing they should have thought through

Comment: They are so busy adding new features they forget to tell people how to use them :)

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time looking through the RCTBundleUrlProvider code, I found this out:

1. If you add an `ip.txt` file to your XCode project with the IP address inside of it it will use that to determine where to get `index.ios`  (without it defaults to `localhost`)
2. `dev=true` is enabled by default (when `setDefaults` is called in AppDelegate.m)
3. You can change dev  by setting `enableDev`

Answer (score 0):

edit your `node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh`  file and remove `xip.io`
in some place(like china), xip.io service not work